# Using optional fields with StaxEventItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application and I'm using the StaxEventItemReader as my ItemReader. By default XStream requires us to declare a property for each possible XML tag or else it throws an UnknownFieldException exception. There are ways to code around this with Java but with Spring Batch, the InputReader doesn't seem to have a way to modify it. Is there a way to flag fields as optional in the xml?

My bean is configured basically like this

```
<job id="synchronizecustomerData" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <step id="readWritecustomers">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk  reader="customerReader" 
                    processor="customerProcessor"
                    writer="customerSyncWriter"                     
                    commit-interval="1"
                    skip-policy="alwaysSkip" >
            </chunk>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
</job>

<bean id="customerReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="customer" />
    <property name="resource" ref="inputResource" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="customerMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="inputResource" class="org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource">
    <constructor-arg value="c:/sf/data.xml" />
</bean>

<bean id="customerMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
    <property name="aliases">
        <util:map id="aliases">
            <entry key="customer" value="com.company.batchmaster.sf.beans.customer" />
            <entry key="name" value="java.lang.String" />
        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerProcessor" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemProcessor">
    <property name="delegates">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customerTransformer" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="customerTransformer" class="com.company.batchmaster.sf.chunk.customerTransformer" />
<bean id="customerSyncWriter" class="com.company.batchmaster.sf.chunk.customerSyncWriter" />
```

My import file looks like this, just getting it up and running

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
<customer xmlns="http://springframework.org/batch/sample/io/oxm/domain">
    <name>ABC Dealer</name>
    <types>CR</types>
</customer>
</records>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: please provide a sample of your xml file and Customer class. Is a property of Customer who throw the exception?

Comment: I updated with more from my xml file. The property causing the exception is 'type'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming `Customer` class has properties `name` and `type`.
Annotate it as [XmlAttribute.defaultValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#defaultValue()) as described in [Jaxb guide](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.5-5/docs/ch03.html#unmarshalling-element-default-values-and-unmarshalling)
No need to this (`<entry key="name" value="java.lang.String" />`) alias because you are unmarshalling a complete Customer object from a  node as specified with `<property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="customer" />`

Comment: The issue is that Customer does not have a 'type' field, sorry I should have included that class in the post. The xml we get back will change over time. I'm trying to design this so if the source system adds a field, that we don't need to update our objects with this new field if we don't care about it.

Comment: I think you have to change 'Customer' class to accept or reject ( depends from the point of view) newly added properties, but this is not a SB issue but a JAXB annotation one. Check around the net how to skip unwanted tags (maybe with @XmlAnyElement)